# Can I turn a 12V 5A (60W) supply into a 5V ~10A (50W)?

Tags: power-supply

I am debating whether to get a cheap high current 12V power supply together with a voltage regulator or an expensive high current 5V power supply for my project. I need about 50W total at 5 volts, which I can do in the two ways listed.

I can get a 5V 10A power supply for about $24. I can get a 12V 5A power supply for about $10. None of them include shipping, they both have 5.5x2.1mm plugs, and are both from UK Amazon.

However, I already have a good 12V 6A (6A not 5A) power supply laying around, which I can use no problem. Can I turn one of these basically into a 5V 10A supply? It can be higher than 10A, but my concern is how much current I would lose in heat and conversion. How much would one of those regulators cost?

Comment: look for buck converters and the reason the 5V is costlier is because of higher current capacity. It translates to components with higher tolerance.

Comment: DC-DC converter is probably around the same price or slightly less on Amazon . If you have a desktop PC or a spare  ATX supply 5V is free.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to get 5V@10A using your existing 12V@6A Power Supply. The only thing needed is a 'good' Step-Down Converter (aka: Buck-Converter). 
Because, your existing supply can deliver up to 72W of power, with the minimum efficiency of around 70% of Buck converter, you can get 50W at the output. And as the required voltage is 5V and input available is 12V, you need 'Buck' type DC-DC Converter.

You can build it your self or buy ready-made. Just google them!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought that was possible. Would something [like this](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/DC-DC-Buck-Converter-12V-24V-to-5V-10A-Step-Down-Voltage-Car-Power-Supply/182775758793) be possible to buy and solder to it? Then I can use my existing 12V 6A power supply and get the 5V 10A I need.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly where a Buck converter comes into use. Its available in market with wide range of input - output DC Voltage and Power. And they have usually an efficiency of above 80%.