# Stepping down DC - maximum current capability

Tags: voltage-regulator, step-down

I'm looking for a bit of a sanity check here (I'm a hobbyist) --

I want to use a 12v regulator capable of outputting 600mA

It's required that it be able to provide enough current to power a 12V to 5V regulator outputting 1000mA.

`12 / 5 = 2.4`, so theoretically the `600mA @ 12V` should be able to provide `1440mA @ 5V`, right?

Comment: Practically it'll be more like 1200mA 5V but yes (assuming the 5V regulator is a buck convertor, not a 7805 or other linear regulator)

Comment: With good switchers this might *just* work but it seems like a relatively bad idea - you don't seem to have left any power budget for a 12v load so why have the intermediate voltage at all?.  What's the overall design and purpose of the system?  Why can't you just create the lower voltage output directly?

Comment: Work on 90% transfer efficiency for each regulator and ask yourself if it still stacks-up.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - The purpose of the 12v regulator is to protect the 5v regulator, which has a maximum input of 18V. It also regulates a 12v signal that I need to output from my system. The input power is from a 12v vehicle electrical system.

Comment: Careful, vehicle systems routinely experience 48v or more surges and spikes.

Comment: This sounds like going about things the wrong way.  Find a 5v switcher with a wider input range, one suitable for automotive use.  If you need a tiny bit of current at a steady 12v, you may actually need a buck/boost to provide that from a car electrical system... possibly even a boost from your 5v.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I actually have an alternate design where I use an automotive grade 5v switcher (36v max input) and used transient tolerant parts on the input, but the problem of keeping the output signal at a steady 12v lead me to think about regulating the input instead. I'll look at a boost regulator from the 5v -- thanks for putting that idea in my head! :)

Comment: You won't get 12v out from a 12v regulator fed from an automotive electrical system when the engine is off.

Comment: @ChrisStratton - Understood! It doesn't need to be a precise 12v, just as long as it doesn't go above 14v or below 10v. I'm looking for boost converts now :)

Comment: Just to be clear - is the 12 to 5 volt regulator a switcher or a linear? If the former, the answer is almost certainly yes, and if the latter the answer is absolutely no.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast - The 5v regulator is a switcher :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are talking about 12V Voltage regulator that can provide up to 600mA, answer to your question is YES.

But since you need 5V input for you system you need to good step down circuit after regulator.

Also this is repeat for question here
[Can I turn a 12V 5A (60W) supply into a 5V ~10A (50W)?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/340477/can-i-turn-a-12v-5a-60w-supply-into-a-5v-10a-50w)